# nltk: Error in collections import

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

I have python 2.7. I am trying to import word_tokenize() and sent tokenise() from nltk.tokenize(). This shows the error.

```
       from collections import defaultdict, deque
ImportError: cannot import name defaultdict
```

This seems to be a name conflict. I imported collections separately and printed it. It is from python library not from nltk. How can I resolve this conflict?

P.S.

Full code

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
s = "nltk is for natural language processing.?"
print sent_tokenize(s)
print word_tokenize(s)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tokenize.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
  File "/home/atul/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from nltk.collocations import *
  File "/home/atul/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 37, in <module>
    from nltk.probability import FreqDist
  File "/home/atul/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/probability.py", line 47, in <module>
    from collections import defaultdict, Counter
  File "/home/atul/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/collections.py", line 13, in <module>
    import pydoc
  File "/home/atul/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/pydoc.py", line 56, in <module>
    import sys, imp, os, re, types, inspect, __builtin__, pkgutil, warnings
  File "/home/atul/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/media/atul/New Volume1/project/Sentiment Analysis/tokenize.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
  File "/home/atul/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    from nltk.tokenize.mwe      import MWETokenizer
  File "/home/atul/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/mwe.py", line 31, in <module>
    from nltk.util import Trie
  File "/home/atul/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/util.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import defaultdict, deque
ImportError: cannot import name defaultdict
```

Comment: What is your full code? Which collections did you import before this? Which function in NLTK is throwing the ImportError?

Comment: You probably have a module named 'collections' in your project.
Try renaming this module in your project.

Comment: @VikramSinghChandel    There is no module named such in my project. But there is one such in python2.7 directory. I triend to rename it. But some other errors started showing.